# Core Bluetooth doesn't find peripherals when scanning for specific UUIDs

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

so I'm pretty new when it comes to bluetooth and I'm currently trying to make it scan for devices, if I try to scan for all devices by using this:

```
self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil);
```

it finds several devices and I printed out the uuidStrings and got several devices uuids but when I try to search for those specific uuids it doesn't find anything, the is the code I'm using:

```
private var uuidArray = ["8B2F2570-9E3B-1FB6-C76E-9258526B662B",
                         "4A29E654-F59F-53AD-D7F6-B435B8BBAB78",
                         "48F038D0-246C-4D62-A025-1D822CAFB93A",
                         "D8E13B7A-BB89-45C2-8747-BAE1D94AE9E0",
                         "558CF744-2C4F-439F-AD7F-E2212938123B",
                         "967B98AC-FFE7-45EC-8D25-0276FBD57FC8"];

func scanForPeripherals (timeout: Double) -> Bool {
    if (self.centralManager.state != .poweredOn) {

        print ("[BLE] Central Manager is not powered on");
        return false;
    }
    print ("[BLE] Start Scan");

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeout, target: self, selector: #selector(stopScan), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    var services: [CBUUID] = [];

    for uuid in uuidArray {
        let cbuuid = CBUUID(string: uuid);
        services.append(cbuuid);
    }


    self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: services, options: nil);
    return true;

}
```

am I missing something here? anyone knows how to find specific devices?

Comment: You scan for service uuids, not device uuids.

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to discover heart rate monitors then you would search for peripherals advertising the heart rate service. There is a list of official services at Bluetooth.org or a peripheral can use any uuid for a "private" service.

Comment: @Paulw11 I see I've been doing that and managed to scan it properly and connect, but now I have another question, it appears to connect properly but it disconnects within a few seconds(2 ~ 5), do you know why? also when running on trying to connect from the iPad I get this:  `[CoreBluetooth] WARNING: The delegate for <CBPeripheral: 0x1740ede00, identifier = 4B181ECF-2BDF-4AE2-B8C9-FFA85A5BE57A, name = phone, state = connected> does not implement -[peripheral:didModifyServices:] `

but it doesn't throw warning when connecting from the iPhone to the iPad and didModifyService is implemented...

Comment: @Paulw11 I managed to solve the warning issue but the device still disconnects, I read in another post that it's a normal behavior but without a reliable source I'm still doubting, do you know anything about that?

Comment: Are you keeping a strong reference to your peripheral. (Ie in a property)